# How can I use ng-select group by for boolean value, with an order and label?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

I have some data:

```
0: {id: 1, name: "hhh", description: "hhh", isPopular: false,…}
1: {id: 2, name: "bbb", description: "bbb", isPopular: true,…}
2: {id: 3, name: "ccc", description: "ccc", isPopular: false,…}
3: {id: 4, name: "ddd", description: "ddd", isPopular: true,…}
4: {id: 5, name: "aaa", description: "aaa", isPopular: false,…}
5: {id: 6, name: "ggg", description: "ggg", isPopular: false,…}
```

I would like to appear in an ng-select as:

> **Popular**
>    bbb
>    ccc
>    **The rest**
>   aaa
>   ccc
>   ggg
>   hhh

So I've used

```
<select ng-selected="true"
    ng-options="category.name group by category.isPopular for category in ctrl.categories |
        orderBy: ['-isPopular','name']"
    ng-model="myModel.category">
</select>
```

However this is returning:

> aaa
>   ccc
>   ggg
>   hhh
>   **true**
>    bbb
>    ccc

How I can label the groups and order by the group?

Comment: have you tried something like `... group by category.isPopular ? 'Popular' : 'The rest' ...`?

Comment: @rob You should make this an answer so others can find it more easily in the future. I'll upvote if you do!

Comment: Will do. Wasn't sure if that would actually work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in the name of the group to `group by`. For example:

```
<select ng-selected="true"
    ng-options="category.name group by category.isPopular ? 'Popular' : 'The rest' for category in ctrl.categories |
        orderBy: ['-isPopular','name']"
    ng-model="myModel.category">
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure if you want to group you should use this:

```
<select ng-selected="true"
    ng-options="category.name for category in ctrl.categories |
        groupBy: 'category.isPopular' |
        orderBy: ['-isPopular','name']"
    ng-model="myModel.category">
</select>
```

`groupBy` is in [Angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter), so you have to get the syntax right.

Comment: angular doesn't have a groupBy filter

Comment: angular-filter does... but I see that's not what he was using now.